# SocialEngine: Display a widget into a modal window using smootbox

Tags: widget, socialengine

I have a widget in the group plugin that displays my groups
I create a button next to "create new group" that is "import group"
I want this button shows me the contents of my widget in a modal window with smooth box
thank you

Comment: just add /format/smoothbox to your url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in this way: Create a new blank action in any controller and view for it. Then render your widget into the view of this action. After that call smoothbox modal window to show needed action with your view which contains your widget. Example of how to show smoothbox by clicking a link below:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlLink(array(
                                 'route'=>'default',
                                 'module'=>'activity',
                                 'controller'=>'index',
                                 'action'=>'viewcomment',
                                 'custom_param'=>$param,
                                  'format'=>'smoothbox'
                           ), 
                           $this->translate('Comment'), 
                           array('class'=>'smoothbox',)) 
?>
```